# vim: Move line containing pattern to the end of above line

Tags: regex, vim

```
A : 
A()
A :
A(int)

to     

A : A()
A : A(int)
```

A() is the pattern I'm searching for (multi-line) and trying to append it to the previous line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using

```
:norm J
```

would work for your current input but I assume that the search is mandatory so you can use a global command like this

```
:g/\vA\(.{-}\)/normal kJ
```

Breakdown

```
g              -- start global command
\vA\(.{-}\)/   -- search for A followed by (<anything>)
normal kJ      -- for each match, execute k (line up), J (join lines)
```

**Edit** *(cudo's to Peter)*

As `-j` in command-line mode is equivalent with `kJ` in normal, you can shorten this to

```
:g/\vA\(.{-}\)/-j
```

or even shorter

```
:g/\vA\(.*\)/-j
```

but personally I prefer the lazy ({-}) instead of the greedy (*) quantifier.

Comment: This is nitpicking, but you could specify that the command is a "colon command", like you did for `:norm J`. I did not know about `g` and naively tried it in normal mode :)

Comment: vim golf: `g/A(.*)/-j`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for substitute:

```
:%s#^\s*\(\k\+\)\s*:\zs\s*\n\_s*\ze\1(.*)# #
```

This way, it'll check that the name matches on both sides of the colon -- it could be `A`, `foobar`, `B`, anything, and you don't need to specify it each time.

`\zs` and `ze` delimit the pattern (any spaces on the same line, a newline, and any spaces (newlines included)) that'll be substituted with a single space. What is around the `\z`one, serves as context where the match shall apply.